# Insert zero between two IDs and make it length 10 in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to Stored Procedures, I am using MSSMS

So what I want is I have a table `aItemPackingDetail` and I have an sp to insert values into the table

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertaItemPackingDetail] 
        @ItemID INT 
       ,@PackingTypeID INT  
       ,@PackingSlNo INT    
       ,@PackingBarCode VARCHAR(25) 
       ,@active BIT

       AS
       BEGIN

       INSERT INTO aItemPackingDetail (
            ItemID      
            ,PackingTypeID      
            ,PackingSlNo        
            ,PackingBarCode     
            ,active     
       )    

      VALUES (      
           @ItemID      
           ,@PackingTypeID  
           ,@PackingSlNo        
           ,@PackingBarCode     
           ,@active     
      )
     END
```

As you can see this is a simple sp for insert. Then I got an update to do. If  `@PackingBarCode` is null or empty I need to create a barcode in sp and save it.

The format of barcode needs to be like

```
@ItemID+ Zeros +@PackingTypeID // length needs to be 10
```

ie. if

`@ItemID = 1212` and `@PackingTypeID = 4521` then `@PackingBarCode
 needs to be`@PackingBarCode
 = 1212004521` so on.

And if length of `@ItemID+@PackingTypeID >= 10` then dont add any zeros.

This as far as I did, I am stuck and no idea how to complete please help.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertaItemPackingDetail] 
     @ItemID INT    
     ,@PackingTypeID INT    
     ,@PackingSlNo INT  
     ,@PackingBarCode VARCHAR(25)   
     ,@active BIT

     AS
     BEGIN

       -- declare variables to store ount ant zeros
       DECLARE @ItemIDcount AS INT  
       DECLARE @PackingTypeIDCount AS INT   
       DECLARE @noofZeros AS INT    
       DECLARE @Barcode AS INT

       -- find count of ids
       SET @ItemIDcount = LEN(@ItemID)  
       SET @PackingTypeIDCount = LEN(@PackingBarCode)   

       -- how many zeros needed
        IF (@ItemIDcount + @PackingTypeIDCount) < 10    
        BEGIN       
              SET @noofZeros = 10 - (@ItemIDcount + @PackingTypeIDCount)    
        END 

       -- if @PackingBarCode becomes null or empty
        IF @PackingBarCode = NULL OR @PackingBarCode = ''   
        BEGIN
               SET @PackingBarCode =  -- how to create barcode??
        END 

INSERT INTO aItemPackingDetail (
            ItemID      
            ,PackingTypeID      
            ,PackingSlNo        
            ,PackingBarCode     
            ,active     
       )    

      VALUES (      
           @ItemID      
           ,@PackingTypeID      
           ,@PackingSlNo    
           ,@PackingBarCode     
           ,@active 
      )
     END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: iam using sql in MSSMS

Comment: Do u have fixed length for `@PackingTypeID` ?

Comment: no I don't have

Comment: And fixed length for first one `@ItemID`

Comment: they are integers and don't have fixed length,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @ItemID INT = 1212
,       @PackingTypeID INT = 4521

SELECT  CASE
            WHEN LEN(@ItemID) + LEN(@PackingTypeID) < 10
                THEN CONCAT(@ItemID, RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000000', @PackingTypeID), 10 - LEN(@ItemID)))
                ELSE CONCAT(@ItemID, @PackingTypeID)
        END AS BarCode
```

Result: `1212004521`

The idea is basically to stick 10 `0`'s in front of @PackingTypeID, and only taking those you need.

Comment: I will check and inform back

Comment: what happens if itemID length exceeds 10

Comment: You get an error, if that can happen you need to check for that as well.

Comment: do I need to check packingtypeId as well?

Comment: Yes,as I said, you do need to build in a check for the case where total length exceed 10.

Comment: I checked the total length, do I need to check alone for itemid and packingtypeid?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
DECLARE
    @ItemID INT = 1212,
    @PackingTypeID INT = 4521

SELECT CAST(@ItemID AS VARCHAR) 
    + REPLICATE('0', 10 - (LEN(CAST(@ItemID AS VARCHAR)) + LEN(CAST(@ItemID AS VARCHAR)))) 
    + CAST(@PackingTypeID AS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: I will check this one

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (apart from concatenating strings) is to solve the problem mathematically, using base 10 logarithms to find the number of digits in each number.

Essentially, you want to multiply the first number by 10 until the number is 10 digits long, and then add the second number. The padding zeroes will automatically be where you want them to be. The only case to cover separately is when the total length is already 10 or greater.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @ItemID BIGINT = 1212,       
        @PackingTypeID BIGINT = 4521

    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN FLOOR(LOG10(@ItemID))+FLOOR(LOG10(@PackingTypeID)) >= 8
                THEN CONVERT(varchar, @ItemID * POWER(10,FLOOR(LOG10(CAST(@PackingTypeID AS FLOAT)))+1) + @PackingTypeID)
            ELSE
                CONVERT(varchar, @ItemID * POWER(10,9-FLOOR(LOG10(CAST(@ItemID AS FLOAT)))) + @PackingTypeID)
        END
END;
GO
```

**EDIT**

Note that the above will preserve the two numbers, regardless of their length, as per the following:

```
@ItemID = 12345
@PackingTypeID = 67891
--> 1234567891

@ItemID = 12345
@PackingTypeID = 678912
--> 12345678912

@ItemID = 1234
@PackingTypeID = 6789
--> 1234006789
```

If you want either of the numbers truncated (see case 2 above), to arrive at a maximum of 10 digits, then you probably need some more logic added. However, if the sum of the digits will never be greater than 10 (before the zeroes are added), then this is a moot point.

Comment: getting an error `{"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."}`

Comment: Did you use the `BIGINT` type?

Comment: Ok... that explains the error. A normal `INT` will not handle numbers with 10 digits. You can create two new variables (only used in the SP) which are `BIGINT`s, to hold the `INT` values from the DB. These are just temporary until you have your barcode `VARCHAR` anyway.

Comment: let me try that