# Check for duplicate in Stored Procedure, and if then change the value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I an working on a Stored Procedure, and I am using SQL.

I asked a question [**Insert zero between two IDs and make it length 10 in Stored Procedure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762900/insert-zero-between-two-ids-and-make-it-length-10-in-stored-procedure/48763151#48763151). I got answer for that and now my solution works fine and this is my sp now.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertaItemPackingDetail] @ItemID INT
,@PackingTypeID INT
,@PackingSlNo INT
,@PackingBarCode VARCHAR(25)
,@active BIT

    AS
    BEGIN
-- Create Barcode if @PackingBarCode is null
IF @PackingBarCode = NULL OR @PackingBarCode = ''
BEGIN
    SET @PackingBarCode = (
    SELECT  CASE
            -- Ceck If total length < 10, then add zeros in between
            WHEN LEN(@ItemID)  + LEN(@PackingTypeID) < 10                   
                THEN CONCAT(@ItemID, RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000000', @PackingTypeID), 10 -( LEN(@ItemID) + LEN(@PackingTypeID)) ),@PackingTypeID)
                ELSE CONCAT(@ItemID, @PackingTypeID)
        END AS BarCode
        )
END


INSERT INTO aItemPackingDetail (
    ItemID
    ,PackingTypeID
    ,PackingSlNo
    ,PackingBarCode
    ,active
    )
VALUES (
    @ItemID
    ,@PackingTypeID
    ,@PackingSlNo
    ,@PackingBarCode
    ,@active
    )
  END
```

Now I want to check duplicate for `@PackingBarCode`, I can check duplicate by following code

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from aItemPackingDetail  WHERE categoryid=@cat and PackingBarCode = @PackingBarCode)
```

But then it get rejected and niot saved, I want to save it, but before saving add `@PackingSlNo` to the end and make it unique, again check for duplicate and if add `@PackingSlNo` once again and so on, when it is not duplicate add it into database.

The duplicate `@PackingBarCode` check needs to done if  `@PackingBarCode` is generated in sp or entered by user.

How do I get there? please help

Comment: it is mysql Or sql?

Comment: the brackets suggest SQL-server and @ variable usage

Comment: First line of question states `MySQL` whereas redirecting question was tagged for `sql server`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, its sql